# How to set a python variable using javascript in JupyterLab

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-lab

In jupyter notebook I can set a Python variable using javascript by doing

```
%%javascript
IPython.kernel.execute("foo=56");
```

However in Jupyter Lab I get *"Javascript Error: IPython is not defined"*

How can I set a python variable using javascript in Jupyter lab, in a similar way to Jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 1):

`IPython` is a JavaScript object which does not exist in JupyterLab, only in Notebooks. See this question:

[Executing Java script code in JupyterLab gives error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72925175/executing-java-script-code-in-jupyterlab-gives-error)

And also this lengthy bug report/discussion on GitHub:

https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5660

TL;DR: Currently there is no approved solution to this, but people are working on it.