# Executing Java script code in JupyterLab gives error

Tags: javascript, python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

I am trying to print a Javascript code to return the notebook URL.

I have the following written in a Jupyter Notebook cell:

```
%%javascript
var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel
var host = window.location.href
kernel.execute("notebook_url='"+host+"'")
```

and when I query for `notebook_url` it gives output as `'http://localhost:8889/notebooks/LTIBootCamp.ipynb'`

[image]

But when I try the same from Jupyter Lab it gives the following error

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

display(Javascript(
    'var kernel = IPython.notebook.kernel'
'var host = window.location.href'
'kernel.execute("notebook_url='"+host+"'")'
))
```

output error:

```
Javascript Error: unexpected token: identifier
```

Comment: You won't be able to do this using *IPython.notebook.kernel* object as it isn't available in Jupyterlab: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5660